# Primitive-recursive functions and polynomial equations

Tags: polynomials, diophantine-equations, computability, recursive-algorithms

I am looking for examples of [primitive-recursive functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function) $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ that can not be written as a pair of polynomials, i.e.

$$f(n) = m \Leftrightarrow P(n,m) = Q(n,m)$$

with $P(x,y), Q(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}_+[x,y]$.

Note that when a Diophantine function

$$f(n) = m \Leftrightarrow (\exists k) P(n,m,k) = Q(n,m,k)$$

(which is *not* of the desired form) and $k$ is *bounded* – i.e. there is a fixed primitive-recursive function $K(n,m)$ with $P(n,m,k) = Q(n,m,k) \Rightarrow k < K(n,m)$ – one can equivalently write

$$f(n) = m \Leftrightarrow \prod_{i=0}^{K(n,m)}(P(n,m,i) - Q(n,m,i)) = 0$$

which *is* of the desired form. (Maybe even for arbitrary computable functions $K(n,m)$?)

So the question is: Are there primitive-recursive functions with

$$f(n) = m \Leftrightarrow (\exists k) P(n,m,k) = Q(n,m,k)$$

where the variable $k$ is not bounded?

Comment: Unless $K(m,n)$ is constant, $\prod_{i=0}^{K(n,m)}(P(n,m,i)-Q(n,m,i))$ is not of the form $P(n,m)-Q(n,m)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(n)=2^n$. And assume there is nonzero $R(x,y)=P(x,y)-Q(x,y)\in\mathbb Z[x,y]$ with $R(n,2^n)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Write $R(x,y)=\sum_{k=0}^K R_k(x)y^k$ with $R_k\in\mathbb Z[x]$ and  $R_K\ne 0$. Then there exist $C, x_0$ with  $|R_k(x)|<C\cdot (\frac 32)^x$ for all $x>x_0$ and all $k$. 
Then for $x>x_0$, $y>1$, $$\left|\frac{R(x,y)-R_K(x)y^K}{y^K}\right|<KC(\tfrac32)^xy^{-1}$$
So if $y=2^x$ and $x_0<x\in \mathbb N$, we conclude
$$ |R_K(x)|<KC(\tfrac 34)^x.$$
Especially, the polynomial $R_K$ is bounded, hence constant, and this constant must be zero, contradiction.